# What is a good way to handle multiple response codes for an API?

Tags: api, rest, http, http-status-codes

Consider a call to a REST API:

```
POST /employees 
[{ "name":"joe", "job":"dev",
 { "name":"bob" }]
```

For each array element an employee would be created. However, job is a required field, so the second element is invalid and the employee cannot be created.

What is a good response for this? 201 or 422?

I saw 207, but it seems to require an XML response, and the API does not use XML. It seems strange to return XML only for this case.

For this particular use case, I am thinking that all valid elements would be used to create resources. But I'm not sure what a good response would be.

Comment: What API? Your own API?

Comment: You could accept a bulk post of employees and return an error response code if just one was wrong. Or, what I would do, write an interface that takes one employee at a time. Then you can have individual response codes. For string data that small you dont have to worry about performance or speeds.

Comment: I would avoid 201 for a bulk post because that might give the users of your API a false sense of success.

Comment: If you cant use the 207 error code. I would rather send 1000 small posts and know each one was successful than have a bulk post and not know what went wrong... Make sense?

Comment: Yes, it is my own API. It doesn't make sense to send many small requests for this use case.

Answer (score 1):

We use 400 for any field validation errors (including missing required fields), be it on a single resource, or an entire collection.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what are you trying to do.

- Process only valid parts from the payload.
- Don't process the payload at all.

In order for something to happen, the entire payload should be valid, not just parts of it. So I wouldn't process only the valid parts of the payload.

I would not use any 2xx status, because that would say to the user that everything worked OK, which isn't true in this situation.

I would not return a 400 status, because the syntax of the payload is syntactically correct JSON, but semantically erroneous.

That would leave us with a 422 status, which is more appropriate in this situation, because like I previously said, you have semantic not syntactic problems.

Comment: That's an interesting point. So, you're really saying that the problem is with processing part of the request. Maybe that is a sort of anti-pattern. But I think there are cases where it makes sense...However, the stinky part is how you let the client know that only part was processed, and which parts is not valid.

Comment: Processing only part of the payload will most likely create more confusion within your user base. I was suggesting to not process anything if `job` field is missing and return a 422 status with a body containing descriptive error message(s). The body could be a json array, so you could include multiple error messages when necessary (_for example a collection in which multiple entries have missing fields_).

Answer (score 1):

I'd stick with @visc advice, i.e., avoid batch processing. I have to say that  @Alexandru Guzinschi advice on all or nothing approach despite being reasonable is not always feasable as sometimes you will become aware of one operation failure only after having tried it.

Both respose codes 207 and 422 you mentioned are defined as HTTP extensions for WebDAV, not in the protocol itself. And it's RFC (4918) is rather obsolete (that's why the suggestion of XML for the 207 response body).

Anyway, If you want to go down this road, I want to clarify  that the use of XML is optional and you could create your own JSON definition. That would be harmless if you're not trying to implement a WebDAV server,

### [RFC 4918](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4918.txt)

"A Multi-Status response conveys information about multiple resources
   in situations where multiple status codes might be appropriate.  The
   **default** Multi-Status response body is a text/xml or application/xml
   HTTP entity with a 'multistatus' root element

Comment: "rather obsolete"?

Comment: No offence. What I meant is that XML has stepped down as "de-facto" standard for formatting messages over HTTP since 2007 when the aforementioned RFC was published.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to have a batch handler.  So, you would send a batch of operations in a single HTTP request, but they are processed as individual operations against the api on the server.  So, the batch response would include the appropriate response code for each individual operation.

A batch request can also include changesets to define transactional behavior.

Your batch could also include calls to different operations as necessary.

You don't state how you are building your api.  If using ASP.NET Web API, there are batch handling capabilities available out of the box.

Comment: FWIW, it's a Rack API.